# How to write a function to count unique values in a column with filter?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have columns "Name" and "GroupID". I want to count the number of unique names whose GroupID is 341. How do I do it?

Comment: An array and a dictionary or sumproduct with countifs.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT with COUNTIFS is generating 0, not sure why